# How to set RootViewController based on JSON data in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to the swift. I am using this [side menu](https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu).

In my Project, 2 Roles are there:

1. Manager
2. Employee

I have to set Side menu and RootVC based on JSON data. In Manager side menu A,B,C,D,E and In Employee side menu A,B,C,D.

Here I am facing a problem. If Role == 5 (Manager), how do I set SideMenu and RootVc and if Role == 4 (Employee) How to set SideMenu and RootVc.

In both cases I have to set different RootVC for manager and employee.

Here I draw one design [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQmWi.jpg). Please someone help me how to solve this issue.

My Appdelegate code

```
@objc func loginUser() {
        let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")
        let role = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Role")
        if userId == nil{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GSLogOutViewController")
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }else{
            var initialViewController = UIViewController()
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            if role == 5{
                initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GSMyTeamViewController") as! GSMyTeamViewController
            }
            else if role == 4{
                initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GSDashboardViewController") as! GSDashboardViewController
            }
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Employee JSON Data:

```
JSON: {
    result =     {
        "Progress_status" = 0;
        Role = 4;
        Source = "default-image.jpg";
        email = "appu.y@gmail.com";
        userId = 32;
    };
    status = 200;
}
```

Manager JSON Data:

```
JSON: {
        result =     {
            "Progress_status" = 0;
            Role = 5;
            Source = "default-image.jpg";
            email = "daya@gmail.com";
            userId = 4;
        };
        status = 200;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried and how your JSON looks like?

Comment: Hi @AndréSlotta i added some code and json data.

Comment: What issue you are facing exactly? Did you call this loginUser function from somewhere?

Comment: Yes @Van I am calling in Applegate.  How to set root view controller after login. I am checking its manager or employee if manager i have to show GSMyTeamViewController else GSDashboardViewController

Comment: That you already have written in your code right? So the point is what issue you are facing in your code? Or is your question like - how to call this loginUser Function?

Comment: Yeah already i have set but side menu button is not showing on the top left bar.

Answer (score 0):

I usually deal with this situation like this:

1- Add all options for both Manager and employee (i.e: [A,B,C,D,E]) in side menu tableview

2- After retrieving the JSON response, check the user type (Manager or Employee)

3- Override tableView delegate function `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 4:
            // 'E' row -> use ternary operator here to check the user role
            // if it's Manager the cell height will be 40.0 (for example)
            // if it's Employee the 'E' row height will be 0.0 (i.e: hidden)
            return role == "Employee" ? 0.0 : 40.0
        break
        default:
            //other rows
            return 40.0
        break
    }
}
```

4- Don't forget to reload the tableView after retrieving the JSON:

`tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: thanks for answering, but here how to set RootVC. In my case, Manager RootVC is different and employee RootVC is different.